# I think there is unintended end and not working well

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, signals

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int stock[5]; // 재고
pid_t pid;

// 주문 가능한 메뉴와 재고 개수를 출력하는 함수
void printMenuStock() {
    printf("Menu and Stock:\n");
    printf("Pizza     %d\n", stock[0]);
    printf("Salad     %d\n", stock[1]);
    printf("Steak     %d\n", stock[2]);
    printf("Chicken   %d\n", stock[3]);
    printf("Beer      %d\n", stock[4]);
}

// 주문 내역을 파일에 기록하는 함수
void recordOrderHistory(const char* format, ...) {
    FILE* file = fopen("Order_History.txt", "a"); //append로
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Can't record order.\n");
        return;
    }
    va_list args; //가변 인자 리스트
    va_start(args, format); // 가변 인자 처리를 위한 초기화
    vfprintf(file, format, args); // 가변 인자를 파일에 출력
    va_end(args); // 가변 인자 처리 정리

    fclose(file);
}
// 주문 내역 출력
void printOrderHistory() {
    printf("\nOrder List:\n");
    FILE* file = fopen("Order_History.txt", "r");
    if (file != NULL) {
        char Order_History[100];
        while (fgets(Order_History, sizeof(Order_History), file) != NULL) {
            printf("%s", Order_History);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}

void handle_parent_signal(int signal) {
    if (pid > 0) {
        kill(pid, SIGINT); // 자식에게 시그널 전송
        wait(NULL); // 종료 대기
    }

    printOrderHistory(); // 주문 내역 출력

    exit(0);
}


int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, handle_parent_signal);
    stock[0] = 1;
    stock[1] = 2;
    stock[2] = 0;
    stock[3] = 0;
    stock[4] = 2;

    int order_count = 0;
    int pipefd_menu[2]; // 메뉴 전달용 파이프
    int pipefd_result[2]; // 결과 수신용 파이프
    int pipefd_stock[2]; // 재고 수신용 파이프

    pipe(pipefd_menu);
    pipe(pipefd_result);
    pipe(pipefd_stock);

    pid = fork();
    while (order_count < 3) {

        char menu[20];

        if (pid == 0) { //자식 프로세스
            close(pipefd_menu[1]); // 메뉴 전달 쓰기용 파이프 닫기
            close(pipefd_result[0]); // 결과 전달 읽기용 파이프 닫기
            close(pipefd_stock[0]);

            read(pipefd_menu[0], menu, sizeof(menu)); // 메뉴 전달 받기
            printf("자식 %s\n", menu);
            // 주문 가능한지 확인
            int menu_index = -1;
            if (strcmp(menu, "Pizza") == 0)
                menu_index = 0;
            else if (strcmp(menu, "Salad") == 0)
                menu_index = 1;
            else if (strcmp(menu, "Steak") == 0)
                menu_index = 2;
            else if (strcmp(menu, "Chicken") == 0)
                menu_index = 3;
            else if (strcmp(menu, "Beer") == 0)
                menu_index = 4;

            if (menu_index != -1 && stock[menu_index] > 0) {
                stock[menu_index]--;
                recordOrderHistory("%s 1 Success\n", menu);
                char success_message[20] = "Success!";
                write(pipefd_result[1], success_message, strlen(success_message) + 1);
                write(pipefd_result[1], &menu_index, sizeof(int));
                exit(0);
            }
            else {
                char fail_message[20] = "Fail";
                recordOrderHistory("%s 1 Fail\n", menu);
                write(pipefd_result[1], fail_message, strlen(fail_message) + 1);
                exit(0);
            }
            //printf("자식");
            //printMenuStock();

        }
        else { // 부모 프로세스
            close(pipefd_menu[0]);
            close(pipefd_result[1]);
            close(pipefd_stock[1]);

            printf("--- Stock ---\n"); // 메뉴와 재고 출력
            printMenuStock();

            printf("Type your order: ");
            scanf("%s", menu);
            getchar();

            write(pipefd_menu[1], menu, sizeof(menu));  // 주문 전달

            wait(NULL); // 자식 프로세스 종료 대기

            char result_message[20];
            read(pipefd_result[0], result_message, sizeof(result_message));
            //printf("%s", result_message);

            if (strcmp(result_message, "Success") == 0) {
                int stock_update;
                read(pipefd_result[0], &stock_update, sizeof(stock_update));
                stock[stock_update]--;
                printf("Success.\n");
            }
            else if (strcmp(result_message, "Fail") == 0)
                printf("Fail.\n");
            order_count++;
        }
    }
    printOrderHistory();

    return 0;
}
```

I am doing homework system programing with using only pipe and signal.
I have to let the program end after receiving 3 orders.
First order is working well, but I type seconde order, the program immediately end. and stock update  in parent process is not working well.
what is problem..??
I made 3 pipes for menu, result and stock update.

Comment: About `if ( pid > 0)` ===> [7.14.1.1, The signal function, C11] — *the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object with static or thread storage duration that is not a lock-free atomic object other than by assigning a value to an object declared as volatile sig_atomic_t.*

Comment: Your signal handler still invokes undefined behaviour. If the handler calls a function that calls async-signal-unsafe functions, the behaviour is still undefined. You can't call `printOrderHistory()` from the signal handler. `exit()` too is not safe. if you wish to exit from such context you will have to do so using `_exit()` instead.

Comment: The code lacks error checking as well. You're only wasting your time if you're not going to check the return values of library/system calls.

Comment: The assignment said that when the parent process ends, the child should also end. And when the parent process ends, I need to print my order history on the console, so how can I do this?

Comment: You're free to call `_exit()`, `write()`, `read()`, `open()` and `close()`.

Comment: void handle_parent_signal(int signal) {
    if (pid > 0) {
        kill(pid, SIGINT);
        wait(NULL); 
    }

    int fd =open("Order_History.txt", "O_RDONLY");
    read(stdout, "Order_History.txt", 100);
    close(fd);

    _exit(0);
} is it right..??

Comment: You could define a variable, e.g. `static volatile sig_atomic_t sigReceived = 0;` to communicate between signal handler and main processing. In `handle_parent_signal` set `sigReceived = 1;` and in your main code at suitable places check the value and react, e.g. `if(sigReceived) break;` to break from a loop or maybe `if(sigReceived) { if (pid > 0) { kill(pid, SIGINT); wait(NULL); } printOrderHistory(); exit(0); }` I suggest to [edit] your question and describe what your program is supposed to do, what input you use, what result you actually get from this input and what you want instead.

Comment: then in handle_parent_signal,  void handle_parent_signal(int signal) {
    sigReceived = 1;

    _exit(0);
} is right?